# Generic Checkbox List View model in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, checkboxlist

I want to create a generic checkbox list view model and so I got this:

```
public class ChckboxListViewModel<T>
{
    public List<CheckboxViewModel<T>> CheckboxList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<T> SelectedValues
    {
        get { return CheckboxList.Where(c => c.IsSelected).Select(c => c.Value); }
    }

    public ChckboxListViewModel()
    {
        CheckboxList = new List<CheckboxViewModel<T>>();
    }
}

public class CheckboxViewModel<T>
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    public CheckboxViewModel(string i_Label, T i_Value, bool i_IsSelected)
    {
        Label = i_Label;
        Value = i_Value;
        IsSelected = i_IsSelected;
    }
}
```

It is used by a different view model to represent filters of different statuses:

```
public class FaultListFilters
{
    public string SearchKeyword { get; set; }
    public ChckboxListViewModel<Fault.eFaultStatus> StatusFilter { get; set; }

    public FaultListFilters()
    {
        SearchKeyword = null;
        StatusFilter = new ChckboxListViewModel<Fault.eFaultStatus>();

        StatusFilter.CheckboxList.Add(new CheckboxViewModel<Fault.eFaultStatus>(FaultManagementStrings.OpenStatus,Fault.eFaultStatus.Open,true));
        StatusFilter.CheckboxList.Add(new CheckboxViewModel<Fault.eFaultStatus>(FaultManagementStrings.InProgressStatus, Fault.eFaultStatus.InProgress, true));
        StatusFilter.CheckboxList.Add(new CheckboxViewModel<Fault.eFaultStatus>(FaultManagementStrings.ClosedStatus, Fault.eFaultStatus.Close, false));

    }
}
```

Now I can't find the right way to display the editors or to create an editor template for that kind of a view model because it is Generic.

I don't want o create a separate editor template for `ChckboxListViewModel<int>` and then another for `ChckboxListViewModel<Fault.eFaultStatus>` and so on..

Is it even a goose idea to use generics in this case?

Is there another way to represent and display a check-box list in MVC?

I have done the following but the modle is not binding for some reason:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FaultManagement", "Faults", FormMethod.Get, null))
{

    for (int i=0 ; i<Model.FaultListFilters.StatusFilter.CheckboxList.Count() ; i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FaultListFilters.StatusFilter.CheckboxList[i].Value)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.FaultListFilters.StatusFilter.CheckboxList[i].IsSelected)
        @Html.LabelFor(m=> m.FaultListFilters.StatusFilter.CheckboxList[i].IsSelected,Model.FaultListFilters.StatusFilter.CheckboxList[i].Label)
    }

    <input type="submit" />
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it even a goose idea to use generics in this case?

Don't think it is.

> Is there another way to represent and display a check-box list in MVC?

I would write a custom HTML helper:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString CheckboxListFor<TModel>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, IEnumerable<string>>> ex, 
        IEnumerable<string> possibleValues)
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(ex, html.ViewData);
        var availableValues = (IEnumerable<string>)metadata.Model;
        var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(ex);
        return html.CheckboxList(name, availableValues, possibleValues);
    }

    private static IHtmlString CheckboxList(this HtmlHelper html, string name, IEnumerable<string> selectedValues, IEnumerable<string> possibleValues)
    {
        var result = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (string current in possibleValues)
        {
            var label = new TagBuilder("label");
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            var checkbox = new TagBuilder("input");
            checkbox.Attributes["type"] = "checkbox";
            checkbox.Attributes["name"] = name;
            checkbox.Attributes["value"] = current;
            var isChecked = selectedValues.Contains(current);
            if (isChecked)
            {
                checkbox.Attributes["checked"] = "checked";
            }

            sb.Append(checkbox.ToString());
            sb.Append(current);

            label.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
            result.Append(label);
        }
        return new HtmlString(result.ToString());
    }
}
```

Then you could have a view model:

```
public class FaultListFiltersViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<string> SelectedStatusFilters { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> AvailableStatusFilters
    {
        get
        {
            return new[] { "Label 1", "Label 2", "Label 3" }
        }
    }
}
```

and inside the view you could use the helper:

```
@Html.CheckBoxListFor(x => x.SelectedStatusFilters, Model.AvailableStatusFilters)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll actually do the same for Radio Buttons and drop-downs ! yo helped me a lot.

Comment: Just a comment i think that `IEnumerable<string> availableValues` would need to be `IEnumerable<string> selectedValues` for clarity purposes ..

Comment: Feel free to edit my post and name the local variables as you like.

Comment: So I have made a lot of edit to support custom Key,Value pairs from the example you gave me and i wish to share it with everyone .. what would be the best practice here ? should i add another answer or should i add an edit to your post ?

Comment: I have added an edit to your post, with all the relevant code examples

Comment: Apparently some other people rejected your edit before I was able to approve it. That's a pity.

Comment: I'll post it as another answer just so people will see another example. thanks !:)

Comment: So i did (post another answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another implementation that will better support bootstrap button-group labels (as it requires them to be seperated) and enum type selected values.

```
    public static IHtmlString CheckboxListFor<TModel, TKey>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, IEnumerable<TKey>>> ex, Dictionary<TKey, string> i_PossibleOptions, object i_LabelHtmlAttributes)
        where TKey : struct, IConvertible
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(ex, helper.ViewData);
        var selectedValues = (IEnumerable<TKey>)metadata.Model;
        var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(ex);
        return helper.CheckboxList(name, selectedValues, i_PossibleOptions, i_LabelHtmlAttributes);
    }

    private static IHtmlString CheckboxList<TKey>(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, IEnumerable<TKey> i_SelectedValues, Dictionary<TKey, string> i_PossibleOptions, object i_LabelHtmlAttributes)
        where TKey : struct, IConvertible
    {
        if (!typeof(TKey).IsEnum) throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enumerated type");

        var result = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var option in i_PossibleOptions)
        {
            var label = new TagBuilder("label");
            label.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(i_LabelHtmlAttributes));
            label.Attributes["for"] = string.Format("{0}",option.Key.ToString());
            label.InnerHtml = option.Value;

            var checkbox = new TagBuilder("input");
            checkbox.Attributes["type"] = "checkbox";
            checkbox.Attributes["name"] = name;
            checkbox.Attributes["id"] = string.Format("{0}", option.Key.ToString());
            checkbox.Attributes["value"] = option.Key.ToString();

            bool isChecked = ((i_SelectedValues != null) && (i_SelectedValues.Contains(option.Key)));
            if ( isChecked )
            {
                checkbox.Attributes["checked"] = "checked";
            }

            result.Append(checkbox);
            result.Append(label);
        }
        return new HtmlString(result.ToString());
    }
```

And then the View Model looks like that:

```
public class FaultListFilters
{
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(FaultManagementStrings), Name = "SearchKeyword")]
    public string SearchKeyword { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<Fault.eFaultStatus, string> PossibleFaultStatuses 
    {
        get 
        {
            var possibleFaultStatuses = new Dictionary<Fault.eFaultStatus, string>();
            possibleFaultStatuses.Add(Fault.eFaultStatus.Open, FaultManagementStrings.OpenStatus);
            possibleFaultStatuses.Add(Fault.eFaultStatus.InProgress, FaultManagementStrings.InProgressStatus);
            possibleFaultStatuses.Add(Fault.eFaultStatus.Close, FaultManagementStrings.ClosedStatus);
            return possibleFaultStatuses;
        }
    }
    public IEnumerable<Fault.eFaultStatus> SelectedFaultStatuses { get; set; }

    public FaultListFilters()
    {
        SearchKeyword = null;
        SelectedFaultStatuses = new[] { Fault.eFaultStatus.Open, Fault.eFaultStatus.InProgress };
    }
}
```

and the usage remains the same (except i have added the label html attributes)

```
    <div class="btn-group">
    @Html.CheckboxListFor(m => m.FaultListFilters.SelectedFaultStatuses, Model.FaultListFilters.PossibleFaultStatuses, new { Class="btn"})
</div>
```